# Unable to send a message to an Objective C method with multiple parameters

Tags: objective-c

I am unable to send a message to an Objective C method with multiple parameters. The method has two parameters, a NSString object and a Boolean variable. I can successfully make the call when I edit my method code so it only has either one of these parameters, but not both. I don't get any compile errors. When I run the program, the program stops and I get a breakpoint at the method call, but the XCode debugger doesn't give any additional info on why it stopped there. I can then choose to continue running the program and it performs as expected. I currently am calling the method from within another method of the same class. I have tried calling the method directly from main, but have the same issue. I have tried numerous changes within the saySomething method, including just commenting out the entire contents of the method, but my program still stops at the method call. My interface and implementation files are below. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Edit: I have also added the code from main as requested.

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

- (void) sayHello;
- (void) saySomething:(NSString *)whatToSay loudly:(Boolean)toYell;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation XYZPerson

- (void)sayHello
{
    NSString *greeting = @"Hello, World!";
    [self saySomething:greeting loudly:YES];
}

- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)whatToSay loudly:(Boolean)toYell
{
    NSString *whatToSayEdited = whatToSay;

    if (toYell == YES) {
        whatToSayEdited = [whatToSay uppercaseString];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", whatToSayEdited);
}

@end
```

---

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...

        XYZPerson *somePerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];

        [somePerson sayHello];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for how you're calling it?

Comment: You get a _breakpoint_? That's not an error. Everything is fine.

Comment: Ok. I figured something was wrong as the program stops its execution and lists the breakpoint at the method call. Is this not an issue?

Comment: No, it's just a debugging tool.

Comment: Sounds like you have a breakpoint set at the

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, I guess I don't have a problem after all. In short, is there a reason why I get a breakpoint with the method call of two parameters, but no breakpoint with a single parameter method call?

Comment: Breakpoints are set at particular lines of your source code. You can set one anywhere you like.

Comment: Ok, I didn't set that one, at least not intentionally. Do they get set automatically?

Comment: I see from ophychius's answer that I probably accidentally clicked a linenumber to create the breakpoint. Thanks for the help though guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a breakpoint set at the

```
if (toYell == YES) {
    whatToSayEdited = [whatToSay uppercaseString];
}
```

block of code, that would explain why without the second parameter it runs smoothly, but stops when you set both parameters.

if it continues to run properly after you tell it to continue it is not an error but really just a breakpoint. Look on the left side of your editor where the line numbers are. Breakpoints appear as blue blocky arrows.

Comment: Thank you - yes, that appears to be what it is. I removed the breakpoint and the program runs without stopping. Is there a simple answer to why that breakpoint got created?

Comment: Remember, the breakpoints only stop your program while debugging in XCode, it will not pause your app while running seperately from Xcode.  Breakpoints easily get created by clicking at the linenumber in your editor. I think all iOS developers have had their share of accidentally created breakpoints.

Comment: Ah ok, I must've accidentally clicked on the line number then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You mean you accidentally discovered the most important debugging tool ever. I very, very strongly suggest that you learn about debugging your code, because I can promise you that you will need it.